# Not able to install locfit r package

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install `locfit` R package, but not able to install on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo). It works fine on my local machine. I get the following error.

```
lf_adap.c(132) (col. 34): internal error: 04010026_1450

icc: error #10014: problem during multi-file optimization compilation (code 4)
make: *** [locfit.so] Error 4
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'locfit'
* removing '/home/a/ahwani/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/locfit'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/Rtmp9zRFVC/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("locfit") :
  installation of package 'locfit' had non-zero exit status


sessionInfo():
     version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

    Matrix products: default
    BLAS/LAPACK: /apps/intel/2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019.1.144/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_intel_lp64.so

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=C                 LC_NUMERIC=C              
     [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
     [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
     [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
     [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.6.0
```

Comment: Are you using the Intel C Compiler?

Comment: Line 132 of `lf_adap.c` lies in a function that is a bit unusual by using bitwise AND and OR (`|` and `&`) where logical AND and OR (`||` and `&&`) seem more logical to me. You can try to download the sources, change that file and install the changed version.

Comment: Yes it is Intel Compiler.

Comment: And did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @RalfStubner I tried on GCC compiler and it worked. Thanks for your suggestion.